# Solve ODE with Scipy solve_ivp where ODE functional form changes with time

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

If I have the following model:

dy/dt = 2- 6t + 3t^2, t <= 1,

dy/dt = y, t >1.

How would I be able to implement this in python using scipy solve_ivp. When I naively implement a while loop within the model definition, the time t does not update and remains 0.0 forever.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def f(t, y):
    while t < 1:
        dydt = 2 -6*t + 3*t**2
        print (t)
    else:
        dydt = y[0]

    return dydt

tspan = np.linspace(0, 4, 20)
yinit = [6]

sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: f(t, y), 
                [tspan[0], tspan[-1]], yinit, t_eval=tspan, rtol = 1e-5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])

plt.show()
```

So in a sense, this is a bit wonkier than a time dependent coefficient since the equation's functional form is changing with time. Would be really grateful for any help here!

Comment: Please debug your code first. Make sure that it works as isolated script or from a cleared workspace. Read up on what a `while` loop does and when execution leaves it.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann The script I have provided here is  MWE that demonstrates the issue. If I were to delete the while loop and simply define dydt as either one of the expressions, it works fine. In a normal solve_ivp script (without the while loop), if I were to include a print(t) line in the model, the t would increase normally till it reaches the final time, which should let me escape the while loop. However, the moment I have the while loop in the model, the t remains 0.0 and doesnt update. Hence the question.

Comment: Ok, I was asking because of `x[0]`. But that assignment is never reached, as the while loop works as expected. You want a branching `if` statement there, not an infinite loop.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah! Just corrected the typo! Sorry about that. Also, the `if` statement works perfectly here! Thanks so much for the help! This is a much cleaner implementation!

Answer (score 0):

My first solution to this which works is to define two separate model equations and another wrapper model equation which enables me to return either equation at a specified time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def f1(t,y):
    dydt = 2 - 6*t + 3*t**2
    return dydt

def f2(t,y):
    dydt = y[0]
    return dydt

def model(t,y,f1,f2):
    while t < 2:
        return f1(t,y)
    else:
        return f2(t,y)

tspan = np.linspace(0, 4, 20)
yinit = [6]

sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: model(t, y,f1,f2), 
                [tspan[0], tspan[-1]], yinit, t_eval=tspan, rtol = 1e-5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])

plt.show()
```

Based on feedback from the comments, the following script seems to work as well if we replace the `while` loop with an `if` statement:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def model2(t,y):
    if t < 2:
        dydt = 2 - 6*t + 3*t**2
    else:
        dydt = y[0]
    return dydt

tspan = np.linspace(0, 4, 20)
yinit = [6]

sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: model(t, y,f1,f2), 
                [tspan[0], tspan[-1]], yinit, t_eval=tspan, rtol = 1e-5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is no real improvement over the code in the question, it just adds some function call structure that is here not necessary or helpful. Also, this seems to be part of the question, so it should be inside the question text.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann, thanks for the feedback. I posted this solution as I found that it works to solve the problem I listed above. It is a bit hacky and im not sure why I cant implement the while loop within a single function for the model and would be grateful for any feedback / help here!

Comment: You have a loop where in the first run-through a return statement is encountered. In contrast in the original variant only a variable is set, without side effects.